# How to create graph structure with distinct parents and children

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graph

I am trying to create a graph structure, where each node has distinct parents and children in JavaScript. So, each node has to be able to have multiple parents and multiple children. I need to be able to differentiate parents and children because I need to represent it hierarchically. I need to be able to achieve something like what is shown below in javascript, but the structure will obviously be larger than that. Is there any way that I can do this?

[image]

So far I have tried doing this with a regular tree structure, and I have also tried this tutorial: https://www.syncano.io/blog/data-structures-in-javascript/, but I can't get it to work in a hierarchical way like I described above.

Comment: Updated my question to show this. Thanks for the advice @BryceDrew.

Comment: You should explain what you are hung up on that you "can't get it to work"

Answer (score 0):

A simple node structure. Each node has distinct parents and children. Here I call if left, and right. What I think you want is a list of children. Make a method to append children to a list of children.

Sorry if this is poorly structured; I normally do CoffeeScript.

https://jsfiddle.net/wx0v4jmt/

```
var left, right;

var Node = (function() {
  function Node(data, left, right) {
    if (left == null) {
      left = null;
    }
    if (right == null) {
      right = null;
    }
    this.data = data;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }

  Node.prototype.get_data = function() {
    return this.data;
  };

  return Node;

})();

var node_4 = new Node("node_4", left=null, right=null);
var node_3 = new Node("node_3", left=node_4, right=null);
var node_2 = new Node("node_2", left=null, right=node_4);
var node_1 = new Node("node_1", left=node_2, right=node_3);

console.log(node_1.get_data())
console.log(node_1.left.get_data())
console.log(node_1.right.get_data())
console.log(node_1.left.right.get_data())
console.log(node_1.right.left.get_data())
```

Comment: What does left and right mean? Are left and right referring to nodes 2 and 3 in the example? I will eventually need to add more nodes than that with their own children.